# Why my wooden table and mouse pad on it measures 12 volt?

Tags: conductivity

I have a non-contact type AC/DC tester which can test 12V - 250V AC and DC. When I put that on my computer table, it shows a 12V reading:

[image: Preview]

The tester that I have has no battery inside.  So there must be a 12V difference between my body and my computer table that's running the tester. If I touch this on my wooden table covered with plastic it shows 12V as well.

There is no direct short-circuit of high voltage with the table. It has the PC 1 feet below the surface.

How can this 12V reading be possible?

Comment: Electric fields exist all through any house supplied by electricity. You don't need to make a physical connection to a wire to measure stuff.

Comment: If it doesn't have a battery inside them at is powering the LCD?

Comment: Here are some fun videos for high potential electric fields.  https://www.electroboom.com/?tag=mosfet&paged=2 , you are measuring low potential electric fields, relatively speaking.

Comment: Hi @Transistor, it doesn't have any battery and it works on principle of induction

Comment: @S.Goswami - Hi, Re: "*The tester that I have has no battery inside.*" Just FYI the similar test screwdriver which I opened had 2 (or perhaps 3, I can't remember) LR44 button cells in series. No external battery compartment, so unless you fully disassembled it, you wouldn't know there were batteries (cells) inside.. That is what powers the LCD section. That primitive LCD section (which is not accurate and doesn't really measure specific voltages, just has a few fixed segments with voltages marked on them) is separate from the induction-powered indication. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, on amazon I read the description that it has no battery and works on principle on induction. My screwdriver is totally sealed, and I am not 100% sure if it has battery. If I can crack open it, I will know (of course it's better to destroy and learn how it works rather than staying ignorant and misinformed).

Comment: @S.Goswami - Hi, Re: "*on amazon I read the description that it has no battery*" Unfortunately incorrect descriptions are well-known on Amazon etc. The similar screwdriver which I had (but have already given away, years ago) could be opened. If you do open yours, then someone might reverse-engineer the PCB for you and write an answer. I know roughly how it works, but I can't remember the details well-enough to write an *accurate* answer.

Comment: Ok, after closely looking at it, it seems like I can open it. Never mind, I also found a youtube video, the language is hindi, but you can watch it and see it has no battery: https://youtu.be/WhhdUieNX5A

Comment: Great - that's different inside to the one I saw, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Can you find (or borrow) another multimeter, to see what voltage it detects? (and show a new picture, if possible).

Comment: Hi, in case of multimeter, there is 0.03 voltage from my body to the table. I have already tested this.